# System that keeps track of inventory with a history table

Tags: sql-server, database, data-modeling

I have a system that lets members rent equipment and the system should have a history of each item that was rented and by who. The system should also track who has what equipment rented/checked out and should also sort the equipment by type, status, name, etc. Lastly it should also send out notification email on equipment that are overdue.

I'm trying to understand the relationships and how I should model this. As of now my current tables and thinking is something like this:

```
Member Table:
Id (PK)
MemberId
FirstName
LastName
Email

EquipmentItem Table:
Id (PK)
EquipmentName
EquipmentType (FK)
EquipmentStatus (FK)
TotalQuantity
RemainingQuantity

EquipmentStatus Table:
Id (PK)
StatusName

EquipmentType Table:
Id (PK)
TypeName

EquipmentRentalHistory Table:
Id (PK)
MemberId (FK)
EquipmentId (FK)
CheckOutDate
ReturnedDate
```

1) I want to know the relationships between these would the rental history be a many to many relationship between the Member table and EquipmentItem table?

2) Would EquipmentItem table have a one to many relationship between the status and type, the way I see it is EquipmentItems can have many statuses or types but each status or each type can only belong to one EquipmentItem.

3) Does it make sense to have a quantity field in the EquipmentItem, I used to work in a grocery store so I'm basing the logic on barcodes where same products would usually have the same barcode e.g. (Cheetos Puff chips) all Cheetos Puff chips would have the same barcode but would have a quantity value on it. Or would it be better to have each item unique regardless if it's the same product/model?

My logic would be:

1. member rents out item
2. system logs it into the history table
3. system then checks how many of the same item has been checked out so far, if say we have total quantity of 4 on that item and 3 members has checked it out
4. we update the remaining quantity field to the difference so in this case to 1
5. system can then track who has what checked out by returning all records with a returned date of null
6. system will then check all records with a returned date of null and then do a date range on the checked out date to determine if the equipment is overdue
7. send notification to member emails associated with said records from step 6

I would just like some help better understanding the relationship between these and if I have modelled my tables correctly, if not, it would be great if someone can point me in the right direction of improving upon this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To answer your questions

1. With respect to modelling in an ERD, I don't think that qualifies as a many-to-many relationship, but rather, `EquipmentRentalHistory` is its own entity that has a many-to-many relationship with both `Member` and `EquipmentItem`.

   A many-to-many would be more like, "a `Member` has access to 0...n `EquipmentItems`, and each `EquipmentItem` can be accessed by 0...n `Members`".

2. I would disagree that they are a one-to-many relationships.

   An oxygen tank and a pair of flippers can both be classified as 'Scuba Gear' and have the status 'Checked Out'.

   You could have multiple 'Scuba Gear' tags and assign each unique 'Scuba Gear' tag to its very own `EquipmentItem`, but then you'll just be creating new tags for every new `EquipmentItem`, rather than reusing existing ones.

3. That really depends on whether you want to identify exactly which piece of equipment a member rented (maybe something is damaged you can track down everyone who rented that specific one?). If you do differentiate, then every item will just be its own row. You should also add a new column as an external identifier, but there would be no need to keep a tally.

   If it's all the same to you, then I would only keep the `total` but not the `available`. If you kept the `available` column, then you would constantly have to update it whenever something is logged in `EquipmentRentalHistory`. This would be annoying if the tables fall out of sync. You could just query `EquipmentRentalHistory` for the `Id` of the equipment, and count up the entries where `returnedDate IS NULL` for the number of equipment that is currently in use

#### Additional Note

It might be good to have a 'due date' column in the rental history rather than hard code the date calculation in case you want to varying due dates. This way you can also grant extensions.